# What is NSKeyedUnarchiver?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a table view. I want to add data into it. I have surfed net and found some sample codes for that. However many of the them are using NSKeyedUnarchiver (encoding, decoding). Why do we need to do this? Any specific reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a way to save and restore data in your app. There are several ways to store and retrieve data in iOS; Core Data, SQLite, plists. `NSKeyedArchiver` is an easy to understand and easy to use class for data persistence. I'd say the reason you're seeing it so much is because it's an easy concept for beginners. The other data persistence methods are less easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a question about a certain class, it's best to look at the Apple documentation. This is directly from the documentation, I hope it clears things a bit for you:

> NSKeyedArchiver, a concrete subclass of NSCoder, provides a way to encode objects (and scalar values) into an architecture-independent format that can be stored in a file. When you archive a set of objects, the class information and instance variables for each object are written to the archive. NSKeyedArchiver’s companion class, NSKeyedUnarchiver, decodes the data in an archive and creates a set of objects equivalent to the original set.
>
> A keyed archive differs from a non-keyed archive in that all the
>   objects and values encoded into the archive are given names, or keys.
>   When decoding a non-keyed archive, values have to be decoded in the
>   same order in which they were encoded. When decoding a keyed archive,
>   because values are requested by name, values can be decoded out of
>   sequence or not at all. Keyed archives, therefore, provide better
>   support for forward and backward compatibility.
>
> The keys given to encoded values must be unique only within the scope
>   of the current object being encoded. A keyed archive is hierarchical,
>   so the keys used by object A to encode its instance variables do not
>   conflict with the keys used by object B, even if A and B are instances
>   of the same class. Within a single object, however, the keys used by a
>   subclass can conflict with keys used in its superclasses.
>
> An NSArchiver object can write the archive data to a file or to a
>   mutable-data object (an instance of NSMutableData) that you provide.

[See more for yourself](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html).